# Don't change the main object when adding a variable to it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to use a variable globally declared, but modify it for the use of a function:

```
var example = {
    selected: '0',
    list: {
        1: {
            value: '1',
            name: "example 1"
        },
        2: {
            value: '2',
            name: "example 2"
        },
        3: {
            value: '3',
            name: "example 3"
        }
    }
};

window.load(function () {
    var example2 = example;
    example2.info = "newinfo";
    // Use example 2
})
```

The problem is, after that, if I console.log(example), it contains the "info" variable, absolutely unwanted. I don't even see why it would have it, I purposely defined a new variable to avoid this.

Comment: assignment != cloning

Comment: I guess you're looking for prototype https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Read [Most elegant way to clone javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: view this question for explainantion as to why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: You are assigning objects by reference, so when you change example or example2 they will change the same reference. 

You have to clone the object then change it.

Comment: Thanks guys it's perfect :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single assignment keeps the reference to the original object. So any changes are reflected to the original object.

Just use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for a copy.

```
var example2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(example));
```